# How to change a Gary Fisher Kaitai Dual Sport to be faster on the road?

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, modification

I have a Kaitai dual sport and I love the bike however, I find myself doing a lot more road riding than off road riding and am looking for things I can do to the bike that will help road rides.  I ride with another person who has a road bike and it is MUCH more efficient.  I can easily ride 5mph faster on that bike with minimal effort.  Would it be possible to change out the tires?  Tires and rims?   Something so I can more easily keep pace, without having to buy a new bicycle?

Comment: The first thing to change would be tires -- go with tires that are thinner, higher pressure, and with smoother tread.

Comment: See "converting a MTB into a roadbike"

Comment: Related: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8577/converting-a-mtb-to-a-road-bike and http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/riding-a-mountain-bike-in-the-city and http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/how-do-on-road-mountain-bike-speeds-translate-to-road-bike-speeds

Answer (score 1):

I changed the tyres on my MTB for slicker ones, The difference was very noticeable and more comfortable. Running higher pressure in the tyres also helps, but be careful not to exceed the tyres recommended max. Also I would recommend reducing the weight if you can, remove any unnecessary parts